# Iterators on the same FeatureCollection provide different results

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geotools

I have a WFSDataStore, which is based on Geoserver. The data are coming from one Database table (with columns ID (unique), NAME, YEAR)

I created a FeatureCollection with following code:

`FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature> fc=(FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature>)WFSFeatureSource.getFeatures(query);`

Then I created 3 Iterators on that fc (I wouldn't do it in real code, I just did it to understand the error I got):

```
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> itr1=fc.features();
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> itr2=fc.features();
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> itr3=fc.features();
```

When I try to get the attribute values, I get different results depending on the iterator:

```
while (itr1.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature ft1 = (SimpleFeature) itr1.next();
    SimpleFeature ft2 = (SimpleFeature) itr2.next();
    SimpleFeature ft3 = (SimpleFeature) itr3.next();
    System.out.println(" Itr1: " + ft1.getAttribute("ID") + ft1.getAttribute("YEAR"));
    System.out.println(" Itr2: " + ft2.getAttribute("ID") + ft2.getAttribute("YEAR"));
    System.out.println(" Itr3: " + ft3.getAttribute("ID") + ft3.getAttribute("YEAR"));
}
```

Output:

```
Itr1: 12458 null
Itr2: 12458 null
Itr3: 12458 2017
```

Does anyone have an idea, how it can be?

Is that a problem of our geoserver configuration may be?

Answer (score 1):

OK, as I supposed, it was a problem with the Geoserver. If you have multiple instances of a server (e.g. on three different ports: servername:8080, servername:8081, servername:8082) make sure to update all of them after changes in the database have been done (Server Status > Reload)